# Prepared statement not working, but writing in terminal when UPDATE works in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement, primary-key

I'm trying to update a table with prepared statement, but I get the error:

```
ERROR fremad.dao.JdbcUserDao - com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '21' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

I really don't get it because I'm not trying to add more rows.

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_meta` (
     `user_id` INT(16) NOT NULL , 
     `first_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL , 
     `last_name` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL , 
     `phone_number` VARCHAR(16) , 
     `birthday` DATE , 
     `home_town` VARCHAR(32) , 
     `profession` VARCHAR(32) , 
     CONSTRAINT `fk_user_meta_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`),
    PRIMARY KEY ( `user_id` )
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

This is the function:

```
@Override
public UserMetaObject updateUserMeta(UserMetaObject userMetaObject) {

    String sql = "UPDATE " + SqlTablesConstants.SQL_TABLE_NAME_USER_META + " SET "
            + "first_name = ?, "
            + "last_name = ?, "
            + "phone_number = ?, "
            + "birthday = ?, "
            + "home_town = ?, "
            + "profession = ? "
            + "WHERE user_id = ?";

    connect();

    try {
        prpstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prpstm.setString(1, userMetaObject.getFirstName());
        prpstm.setString(2, userMetaObject.getLastName());
        prpstm.setString(3, userMetaObject.getPhoneNumber());
        prpstm.setDate(4,userMetaObject.getBirthday());
        prpstm.setString(5, userMetaObject.getHomeTown());
        prpstm.setString(6, userMetaObject.getProfession());
        prpstm.setInt(7, userMetaObject.getUserId());
        prpstm.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.error(e.toString());
        return null;
    } finally {
        close();
    }
    return userMetaObject;
}
```

And when I tried to paste this directly in to the terminal and it succeeded:

```
UPDATE user_meta SET first_name = "John", last_name = "Doe", phone_number = "81549300", birthday = "1988-05-24 00:00:00", homeTown = "Lillehammer", profession="Student" WHERE user_id = 21;
```

What am I doing wrong? Please tell me if you need any more info..

Answer (score 0):

When you tried your query in console there was user_id=5, but you get exception with user_id=21. It seems that you already has row with user_id=21!

Comment: I'm sorry about that. That was only because I copied the wrong line. I've tried several times, you see.. I've fixed the typo. And also, I do want to update the existing fields, not create a new row. Fyi: there was a user with both user_id = 5 and user_id = 21.

Answer (score 0):

When I have strange behaviors like this, it is common that the problem might be related to some trigger that you might not be aware of, if not, I would suspect from the fact that your primary key is also a foreign key, some databases have problems with that.

Comment: How is it different to use a prepared statement instead of writing directly into the console? The database should allow both or none, right?

Comment: That's difficult to answer, what if your program is in autocommit mode and the console is not, or what if you ran your console query in an open transaction and then the program, while the transaction is still pending, or maybe your program is running something else before your update that might be interfering, well these are only posibilities, maybe you would consider running more tests. When I have a difficult problem I write the smallest program that reproduces it. I remember I had a problem with an Oracle DB that produced garbage after an update, and at the end it was a bug in the DB.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'll post a solution if I find one.